# null value in entry: manifests=null

Tags: spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

I've created a Deploy manifest step for kubernetes. I've got a bake step and I see an yaml file being created. I've tested access via kubectl on the spinnaker  statefulset and can see pods. So I've confirmed network and acl is working but I'm still unable to do deployment. The error is really vague and I'm not sure where else to look.

Answer (score 0):

The Clouddriver deployment needed restarted.